# Saving over files in source in Chrome Developer tools has stopped working

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools, chrome-dev-editor

I previously enjoyed making changes in CSS in Chrome Developer Tools, then saving over the CSS file in my local storage, using sources tab.

This now has stopped working. I can save as, replace, but the css file no longer replaces, when I refresh browser all my changes are lost.

Any advice?

[image]

Comment: This question is off-topic here. I think you ask this on http://superuser.com/questions/ask

Comment: I don't understand why is this off topic? I can't post this question on superuser, I don't have enough points